# Configuring PyDev for Eclipse in Mac X Lion

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, python-3.x, pydev

Mac's default Python client is v2.7.  How can i configure PyDev for Eclipse to use 3.2 instead?  I cannot find the interpreter for Python 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a new python version from http://python.org and when configuring PyDev, point to that version (ideally, never use any installed version already in the system and always download and use the version from http://python.org for development purposes as Mac versions are not suitable for development as they don't come with sources -- and also, if you break something there you may break something in your system).